# Open file user specifies

Tags: python, file, rename

I'm being a nooby at python and can't seem to get my program to do what I want it to. I want the user to specify a .gif file they want to open and then the program will display the `.gif` they specified. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. If someone could please help me out I would greatly appreciate it. I want them to specify the file, program then renames file to "variable" in folder. Open file called `"variable.gif"` in `/path/path/variable.gif`

```
files = listdir(".")

print("List of GIF files in Directory:")
for f in files:
    if f[-4:] == ".gif":
        print(f)
print("type quit to close the program")     
gif1 = input("type which .gif you would like to modify and press enter:")
infile = open(gif1, "r")
outfile= open("gif1.gif", "w")
os.system('eog {0}'.format(r'home/pictures/gif1'))
```

Comment: Arrite, I'm working on this right now.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename

Comment: Use `for f in glob.glob('*.gif'): print f` if you want just `.gif` files.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code snippet and let us know if it works

```
import os

files = os.listdir(r'/home/pictures/')

print("List of GIF files in Directory:")
for f in files:
    if f.endswith('.gif'):
        print(f)
print("type quit to close the program")     
gif1 = input("type which .gif you would like to modify and press enter:")

if gif1 in files:
    os.system(r'eog /home/pictures/{0}'.format(gif1))
else:
    print 'The file name you entered is incorrect
```

The code you posted does not work because the program **eog** expects only the filename not the opened file handle. Also **gif1** is input by the user, hence only **gif1** must be appended to the string **/home/pictures/**

When you do a call to `open(filename,'r')` what you actually get is a file handle. This file handle cannot be passed as a command line argument to another program. Also another point is to replace anything like **/home/pictures** with something like **~/pictures/**

Comment: it continues to say that the file gif1 is not found in the designated location even though I checked and it is there. However it opens other files in the same folder. Thanks for your help too, I really appreciate it. 

I also get an error message when I try opening gif1.gif as it says the .gif file i truncated or incomplete.

Comment: Updated my answer - there was a typo error due to copy paste. The stuff should work now

Comment: No images found in 'file:///home/pictures/hibiscus.gif'.

That is the error message that I'm getting in the image viewer when I try to run the program. I think it has something to do with the gif1.gif file error message when I try to open it manually about being truncated or incomplete.

Comment: it looks like it is creating the gif1.gif file but for some reason it isn't being created properly. Not sure how to fix this :/ hrmmmm.

Comment: The script you posted does not create any file - it only launches the EOG program to open up a GIF image. Is there something I am missing here? By the way, I edited my answer to list all GIF files in the  /home/pictures directory. The previous way of os.listdir('.') will list all GIF files from the directory where the python script is located.

Comment: I was under the impression that outfile = open("gif1.gif", "w") rewrote the .gif file as gif1.gif so that I could then have that be the desired out put that the user specified as long as their selection was originally a .gif that could be relabled gif1.gif.

Comment: From your question it seems like you only wanted to open files - hence the code in my answer helps you to do so.

Comment: @user2925055 Did you get the solution to your problem?